# Pivotal doesn't display logs from STDERR

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, cloud-foundry

I use standard buildpack on Pivotal and there are no logs at all from STDERR when using 'cf logs app_name' - for example no exception stack traces. 
I've looked at Loggregator (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/loggregator) and there just shouldn't be a problem. 
I've also made sure my CF_TRACE env variable is set to true also JBP_LOG_LEVEL and LOG_LEVEL to DEBUG.

I've set up tester app on Pivotal with simple Tomcat servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(value="/errTest", name="err-test")
public class ErrTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
     throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("System.out TEST");
    System.err.println("System.err TEST 1");
    System.err.flush();
    System.err.println("System.err TEST 2");
  }
}
```

with the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>errTesting</groupId>
  <artifactId>errTesting</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

On Pivotal (cf logs ) there is following output:

> 2014-10-08T12:55:28.63+0200 [App/0]   OUT System.out TEST

while on localhost:

> System.err TEST 1 System.out TEST
>   System.err TEST 2

Are there any configurations option that I may have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Anything sent to STDERR (and flushed if necessary) will show up in `cf logs` (loggregator) in RED. Anything sent to STDOUT (and flushed if necessary) will show up without color.

If they aren't showing up, perhaps try some explicit flushing? (`System.err.flush()` perhaps?)

Comment: It doesn't work, the problem lays probably in Tomcat config although I've tried changing default_log_level (logging.yml) from INFO to DEBUG in my build-pack but it doesn't work either.